# Bluetooth pairing pop up in android is appearing in two dialog screen one is (just pair) and another one is user enter pin

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

While initiating pairing firstly it will ask pair with device (device name)i.e just pair pop up appears on click of OK button one more pairing pop up appears requires user input (pin)is required to pair. I want a user input pairing pop up dont want just pair pop up we require only one pop up in android device. How do we archive in android devices? Please suggest.

I observed in IOS devices we are receiving only one pairing pop up dialog i.e ( user to enter pin) but in android devices we are receiving 2 pop up dialog. Please let me know the root cause.

I am using Xamarin forms to run on android & IOS . I tried to initiate the pairing by reading characteristic and receiving two pairing pop up. in IOS it is only one.

Comment: It is an Android bug. Use createBond to connect to the device as a workaround....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.